# Get a result from callback scrapy request immediately

Tags: python, request, response, scrapy

I am not sure that my question is correct, but I am quite new in scrapy. Therefore, all comments related to the topic will be useful.

My problem is I have a website with structure( as json document like ):

```
{ 2: { 
       1: 'http://example.com/1.jpg', 
       2: 'http://example.com/2.jpg'
} 
...// bunch of other information
}
```

and links are related, but I need direct link to this images.
I am trying to solve this task as:

> urlData = scrapy.Request(url='http://myserver/1.jpg',
>   callback=self.parse_link)

where the callback function is:

```
 def parse_link( self, response ):
    Hxs = scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    Data = LacBacLink()
    link =  Hxs.select("(//img)[1]/@src").extract()
    Data["Link"] = link
    return Data
```

I consider that it will work properly if I am able to get result from callback request function in scrapy immediately.

I have tried to write the code presented into documentation:

```
 def parse_page1(self, response):
    return scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                          callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    # this would log http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    self.logger.info("Visited %s", response.url)
```

It does not work for me. If you know how to solve this task using this code, please, give me any realisation for better understanding.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work for me"? Any errors? Thanks.

Comment: I mean that I need return whole object. But only examples that I found and tried give me pieces of a code.

Comment: And I do not know how adopt them to my needs.

Comment: Not sure I'm following, do you mean you want to use smth like `response.body`?..

Comment: I mean that I have `url` and I would like to pull data from this `url` instantly. `urllib, urllib` and other such libraries do not work good, because I need more than ~100000 responses and requests. The answer on your question: it is the same as `response.url`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Correct me if I'm wrong: you want to extract the absolute image urls and store them (just the urls)?

Comment: I will try to specify my needs. `object = {2 :{ 1: link1, 2: link2 }, Field1: Data1, Field2: Data2 }` . It is an example of a file I exactly need link1(relative) -> link1(direct). `object` should be returned from `parse ` function.

Comment: You can't use a request call back this way. It is the scrapy crawler making these call backs happen from within the scrapy engine part of their architecture. Therefore the crawler is expecting and item or a request to be returned/yielded. Please read up on their architecture if you want more of an understanding. Your only two options are to make another request (urllib, requests library, etc -- not scrapy.Request) from within the parse_page1 function. I don't recommend this though. My answer below has a more scrapy style approach.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't working code -- read the comments I added.

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    # here you would collect all the information that you need from the first page and put it in an item
    r = scrapy.Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                          callback=self.parse_page2)
    r.meta['item'] = item
    yield r

def parse_page2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    # add what you need from this response to the item
    yield item # if you need to parse more pages yield a request instead.
```